Using img.at to set the color of individual pixels in OpenCV C++
I am relatively new to OpenCV. I want to set the colour of individual pixels using img.at
I also kind of understand cv::Scalar, for example cv::Scalar(0,255,0) is green, cv::Scalar(255,0,0) is blue
I tried the following code
int main( void ){
  cv::Mat img(400,400, CV_8UC3);

  for(int i=0; i < 400; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j < 400; ++j){
      img.at<cv::Scalar>(i,j) = cv::Scalar(0,255,0);
    }
  }

  cv::imshow("Tetris", img);
  cv::moveWindow("Tetris",400,400);

  cv::waitKey(0);

}

It compiles without error messages, but if I launch the program, nothing is visible at all.
How do you set the colour of an indiviual pixel to red, green or blue?

Are you sure the program is running correctly? What's the return code of the process? Have you tried using a debugger?

from gawking at the source, I would expect to see something but it should look like noise/garbage.

@ChristophRackwitz I think the only non-zero values would be left past the end of the buffer. If I'm not mistaken, the first 8 bytes (the first double of the Scalar) will be all zeros, but it makes only 3 byte steps, so the non-zero bytes will keep being overwritten. (AFAIK the indexing works the same irrespective of the template argument).

yeah, double 0.0 does encode to eight bytes 0xFF (just checked with python's struct). if it's striding by the Mat's element stride, that would match. I don't know either, what stride it would use. to be sure, one might wanna check the area of an 8UC3 image that can be painted by an at<uint8_t>(i,j). (un)fortunately, OpenCV doesn't expose this awful method to Python, so I am unlikely to bother trying this myself.

Your cv::Mat type is CV_8UC3, meaning it contains 3 channels, each of them a uchar.
But cv::Scalar contains 4 elements, and by default each of them is a double.
cv::Vec3b is a convenient type to represent an RGB value, where each channle is a uchar.
Therefore instead of:
img.at<cv::Scalar>(i,j) = cv::Scalar(0,255,0);

Use:
//-----vvvvvvvvv----------vvvvvvvvv------------
img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(0, 255, 0);

Note that although it doesn't matter in the posted example, the indices that you pass to cv::Mat:at should be row index (AKA y) first and column index (AKA x) second.
A side note:
Using cv::Mat::at in such a tight loop to set the pixels of the entire image is not very efficient (due to some validations performed in each at call).
A better approach would be to iterate over the rows, and for each row iterate via a pointer to the beginning of the row with cv::Mat::ptr.
Also you should be aware that if you need to set all the pixels of an image to the same value, you can use cv::Mat::setTo method.

Following the request from the OP, here's an example of using cv::Mat::ptr to set image pixels more efficiently.
As mentioned above, if in the real case all pixels should have the same value, you can simply use cv::Mat::setTo instead.
for (int row = 0; row < img.rows; ++row) {
    auto* pRowData = img.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(row);
    for (int col = 0; col < img.cols; ++col) {
        pRowData[col] = cv::Vec3b(0, 255, 0); // assign the pixel with the relevant value (here green is just an example)
    }
}


Side side note: Since OP is setting all the pixels to the same value, a single call to cv::Mat::setTo would probably be a good choice.

@DanMašek proper side side note ;-) But as I understood it, setting to the same value was just an example and the OP would like to understand the issue of setting image pixels in general. Added a note about it anyway.

@wohlstad I am totally lost of implementing what you meant with cv::Mat::ptr. Can you edit the answer to provide that code also?

@user172501 I updated my answer with an example of using cv::Mat::ptr.

@wohlstad Thanks a lot

@user172501 happy to help !
